# R Reformat Data

Tags: r, data.table

```
DATA = data.frame(      STUDENT =c( 1   ,   2   ),
                       CLASSROOM=c('A', 'B'),
                        TIME1   =c( 5   ,   7   ),
                        TIME2   =c( 9   ,   8   ),
                        TIME3   =c( 11  ,   10  ),
                        ENG1    =c( 4   ,   6   ),
                        ENG2    =c( 0   ,   NA  ),
                        ENG3    =c( 3   ,   1   ),
                        MATH1   =c( 7   ,   9   ),
                        MATH2   =c( 6   ,   1   ),
                        MATH3   =c( 6   ,   8   ))
```

I have data in the format above but wish to convert it to data like this:

```
WANT = data.frame(STUDENT = c(1, 2),
                  ALL = c("A, 5, 4, 7; 9, 0, 6; 11, 3, 6", "B, 7, 6, 9; 8, NA, 1; 10, 1, 8"))
```

Where Essentially, the data are combined such as:

```
CLASSROOM, TIME1, ENG1, MATH1; TIME2, ENG2, MATH2; TIME3, ENG3, MATH3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic methods that don't depend on the number of triplets.

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_*
DATA %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(STUDENT, CLASSROOM), names_pattern = "(.*)([0-9]+)", names_to = c(".value", "num")) %>%
  summarize(value = paste(TIME, ENG, MATH, sep = ", "), .by = c(CLASSROOM, STUDENT, num)) %>%
  summarize(ALL = paste(value, collapse = "; "), .by = c(CLASSROOM, STUDENT)) %>%
  mutate(ALL = paste(CLASSROOM, ALL, sep = ", "), CLASSROOM = NULL)
# # A tibble: 2 × 2
#   STUDENT ALL                           
#     <dbl> <chr>                         
# 1       1 A, 5, 4, 7; 9, 0, 6; 11, 3, 6 
# 2       2 B, 7, 6, 9; 8, NA, 1; 10, 1, 8
```

## data.table

```r
library(data.table)
tmp <- melt(as.data.table(DATA), id.vars = c("CLASSROOM", "STUDENT")
  )[, c("var1", "num", "variable") := c(tstrsplit(variable, "(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)", perl = TRUE), list(NULL))
  ] |> dcast(CLASSROOM + STUDENT + num ~ var1, value.var = "value")
tmp[, .(ALL = paste(TIME, ENG, MATH, sep = ", ")), by = .(CLASSROOM, STUDENT, num)
  ][, .(ALL = paste(ALL, collapse = "; ")), by = .(CLASSROOM, STUDENT)
  ][, c("ALL", "CLASSROOM") := .(paste(CLASSROOM, ALL, sep = ", "), NULL)
  ][]
#    STUDENT                            ALL
#      <num>                         <char>
# 1:       1  A, 5, 4, 7; 9, 0, 6; 11, 3, 6
# 2:       2 B, 7, 6, 9; 8, NA, 1; 10, 1, 8
```

`data.table` doesn't (yet?) have an easy way to melt "part" of variables (even with `patterns(.)`) in the same way that `tidyr` uses its `names_pattern` and `".value"`.

Comment: what if it instead of TIME1, TIME2, TIME3 is a1TIME, a2TIME, a3TIME

Comment: are the other fields also renamed, or are they inconsistent?

Comment: If they're all consistently `a#WORD`, then `pivot_longer(-STUDENT, names_pattern = "([0-9]+)(.*)", names_to = c("num", ".value"))` works. Notice the change in both the _pattern_ and the order of the `names_to=` vector.

Comment: perfecto! last question, what if there are some one off names? Like, CLASSROOM which does not change over time...

Comment: I'll guess `pivot_longer(-c(STUDENT, CLASSROOM), ...)`

Comment: thank you 100% but when I try that then CLASSROOM value get left out of the value column where it goes. I update the original question

Answer (score 3):

Here's a more generic tidyverse method

```
library(tidyverse)
DATA %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(STUDENT, CLASSROOM), names_pattern = "(\\w+)(\\d+)", names_to=c("sub","idx")) %>% 
  mutate(sub = fct_inorder(sub)) %>% 
  arrange(STUDENT, idx, sub) %>% 
  group_by(STUDENT, CLASSROOM, idx) %>% 
  summarize(value = paste(value, collapse=', ')) %>% 
  summarize(value = paste(value, collapse='; ')) %>% 
  mutate(value = paste(CLASSROOM, value, sep=", "), CLASSROOM=NULL)
#   STUDENT value                         
#     <dbl> <chr>                         
# 1       1 A, 5, 4, 7; 9, 0, 6; 11, 3, 6 
# 2       2 B, 7, 6, 9; 8, NA, 1; 10, 1, 8
```

We reshape the data, and then collapse it into groups based on the IDs

Comment: what if it instead of TIME1, TIME2, TIME3 is a1TIME, a2TIME, a3TIME and there are some static names that do not have time component, such as CLASSROOM

Comment: I update the question, plz let me know if you know how to modify this. I try with no success

Comment: I've updated the answer to account for the extra column

Comment: that adds it as new column but I want it to be under the 'value' column

Comment: You can add an extra `paste` step. But it seems odd that your first group before the semi colon will have 4 entries but all the others will have 3. Are you sure that's the format you want?

Answer (score 1):

Using tidyverse:

```
DATA <- DATA %>% rowwise() %>% 
         mutate(ALL = paste( paste(TIME1, ENG1, MATH1, sep=", "),
                             paste(TIME2, ENG2, MATH2, sep=", "),
                             paste(TIME3, ENG3, MATH3, sep=", "),
                             sep="; ") %>%
         select(STUDENT, ALL)
```

Comment: is there a way to do it where I do not have to say the variable? For example, if I have 10 times points and 9 VARIABLES it is a lot to text is there a automate way?

Comment: @bvowe Yes: see the (better) [answer by MrFlick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76924613/2189127).

Answer (score 1):

A general base R approach using `grep` may be:

```
col1 <- grep("1", colnames(DATA))
col2 <- grep("2", colnames(DATA))
col3 <- grep("3", colnames(DATA))

NEW <- data.frame(STUDENT = DATA[,1],
                  ALL = apply(DATA, 1, \(x) paste(paste(x[col1], collapse = ", "),
                          paste(x[col2], collapse = ", "),
                          paste(x[col3], collapse = ", "),
                          sep = "; "))
)
```

Output

```
  STUDENT                         ALL
1       1  5, 4, 7; 9, 0, 6; 11, 3, 6
2       2 7, 6, 9; 8, NA, 1; 10, 1, 8
```

Answer (score 1):

A general base R approach:

```r
var.gr <- 'STUDENT'
# individual variables (TIME, ENG, MATH)
vars <- unique(sub('[0-9]+$', '', setdiff(names(DATA), var.gr)))
# number of timepoints (3)
n <- (ncol(DATA) - 1) / length(vars)
# combine data from each time point
tmp <- lapply(seq_len(n), \(i) 
              apply(DATA[, paste0(vars, i)], 1, paste, collapse=', '))
# combine data from each student
tmp <- do.call(mapply, c(tmp, FUN='paste', sep='; '))
cbind(DATA[var.gr], ALL=unname(tmp))
#   STUDENT                         ALL
# 1       1  5, 4, 7; 9, 0, 6; 11, 3, 6
# 2       2 7, 6, 9; 8, NA, 1; 10, 1, 8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by reshaping and combining the columns of your original data frame.

```
    # Original data
DATA = data.frame(
  STUDENT = c(1, 2),
  TIME1 = c(5, 7),
  TIME2 = c(9, 8),
  TIME3 = c(11, 10),
  ENG1 = c(4, 6),
  ENG2 = c(0, NA),
  ENG3 = c(3, 1),
  MATH1 = c(7, 9),
  MATH2 = c(6, 1),
  MATH3 = c(6, 8)
)

# Reshape the data
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

WANT <- DATA %>%
  mutate(
    ALL = paste(TIME1, ENG1, MATH1, sep = ", "),
    ALL = paste(ALL, paste(TIME2, ENG2, MATH2, sep = ", "), sep = "; "),
    ALL = paste(ALL, paste(TIME3, ENG3, MATH3, sep = ", "), sep = "; ")
  ) %>%
  select(STUDENT, ALL)

# Display the result
print(WANT)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user(James_D) already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up once you have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Another base R approach is to split the data columnwise and then paste the values together:

```
s <- split.default(DATA[-1], sub("\\D+", "", names(DATA)[-1]))
fn <- function(x, sep)do.call(paste, c(x, sep = sep))
cbind(DATA[1], ALL = fn(lapply(s, fn, ', '), '; '))

  STUDENT                         ALL
1       1  5, 4, 7; 9, 0, 6; 11, 3, 6
2       2 7, 6, 9; 8, NA, 1; 10, 1, 8
```